# How can we get cluster level metrics in Solr?

Tags: java, solr, solrcloud

I am trying to read cluster level load and performance metrics from Solr. The only reference I can find is here[Solr Cluster Reporter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/metrics-reporting.html#cluster-reporter). I am not able to get it to work. Has anyone successfully got it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one in Solr metric reporter.

Solr metrics reporter has metrics organised into different registries; core, jvm, node, and cluster. What you are looking at is performance metrics at cluster level, which means a node has to aggregate the performance metrics from `node` registry, which isn't very useful considering a cluster can have different collections and cores can differ very much in system configuration.